# What is the Ruby tool that allows for bootstrapping an OS X environment?

Tags: ruby, macos

For the life of me I can't find the tool I ran across yesterday. It's not Homebrew (I already use Homebrew) what I found was a tool that I think was built in Ruby that allowed for installing regular .app applications and otherwise scripting most of an OS X config (I assume preferences and other things). I already have a script based on the Thoughtbot Ruby environment that I'm able to run successfully but I'd love the ability to script installing the other 20-30 apps that I use so that it would make reformatting a little easier.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the tool I was looking for.

https://github.com/benhoskings/babushka

Answer (score 0):

You might be thinking of a [configuration management](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_open_source_configuration_management_software) tool like [Chef](http://www.opscode.com/chef/). You can use this to bring up a system from a bare OS to the configured state defined in your recipes.

Personally I've only used it for setting up linux servers, but I think it would work just as well for launching installers and running configuration scripts on a Mac.

Comment: Thanks for the response, unfortunately it's not Chef or Puppet or Macports or Fink... it was something I'd never heard of.

Comment: Ok, I'm starring your question then... I'm curious to know. :)

Comment: I found it FINALLY... in my Safari history list (I always use Chrome...sigh)

https://github.com/benhoskings/babushka

I'm not actually sure it'll do everything I want or if it's truly different that Chef or whatever, but I'm going to poke around and see what it's all about :)

Thanks,
-Jon